# Android - SQLite database on SD card

Tags: android, database, sqlite

is there any way, how to create and use database from SD card in my app instead of /data/data/com.myapp/databases directory? I know is it unsecure, but are there any special restriction like "database on SD card cannot be bigger then 2GB"?

Thanks

Hmyzak

Answer (score 9, accepted):

he is a proposed solution which i found in stackoverflow

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/android/com.myapp/databases/mydatabase.db" ); 
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
System.out.println("Its open? "  + db.isOpen());
```

here is the **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055188/can-i-download-an-sqlite-db-on-sdcard-and-access-it-from-my-android-app/1055566#1055566)**.

**UPDATE**

i am not sure you can use this along with SQLiteOpenHelper, but you sure can query the database object.

```
db.getVersion();
db.execSQL(sql);
db.beginTransaction();
db.endTransaction();
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

you can do all the things which you expect with a database. SQLiteOpenHelper in only a wrapper class which helps you the extra which we always can do on our own.

**EDIT**
as for your file size limit i found this link. [Is there a file size limit on Android Honeycomb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217744/is-there-a-file-size-limit-on-android-honeycomb/5217950#5217950)

Comment: Nice but, how to use it with SQLiteOpenHelper class, which defines my database?

Comment: @WayPoint, In  my case, I have no need  another chunk or helper, With the above way  all work is done easily, Thanks@samuel, struggling all the day  I found it at last, Alhamdulillah.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class :

```
public class ExternalDBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public ExternalDBHelper(Context context, String DATABASE_NAME,  int DATABASE_VERSION) {
        super(context, DirectoryManager.getDir(context, DirectoryManager.ChildDir.Databases, DirectoryManager.ForcePath.SDCard)
                + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Use :

```
 ExternalDBHelper helper = new ExternalDBHelper(context,dbName,  CLeitner.Constant.DATABASE_VERSION);
 SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```