# browse sqlite database from device

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need help to create an android application as I completely new to android.
I want to develop an application  which will be able to perform database related operations on my android phone using that application.like it should allow user to see how many databases are there in my device.

when I select database,tables should display on my device and allow user to perform insert, delete, update operations. And also allow  user to create new database.anybody is there to help me ? thanks .

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056395/get-app-sqlite-database-programmatically-in-file

Comment: u can use root apk to view for same

Comment: @Bhakti u need to R&D something. 99% u cannot access other database or table u can only access your applications database and tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases are **application-specific** in Android. One app can't touch the database of other app hence you **cannot** retrieve **ALL** the databases present in the system.(And i guess you shouldn't do that too) An android app can manipulate only its own database (There is something called as content-provider to use other app's database but other app should permit to do so).
Hence,you will not be able to create your desired application which you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

user cant able to see database from device... so you have to get data from database programmatically and then inflate all data from database in to your application so that user can able to see the data which is resides in DATABASE

Comment: ok .but should i create new data base on button click and store it to my sdcard and then access that database to view table inside it.is it possible

Comment: no its not possible to view database..you can create database clicking on button but you wont to see it

Comment: @Bhakti You have to create database in your app and fetch data from that database. Simple!!