# forensic tool for Android

Tags: android

I am doing a forensic course and as a requirement I have been asked to develop a forensic investigation tool (windows based) for Google's Android OS. The requirement is such that given an image file, the tool should be able to display the databases that the applications are using, call history, messages and etc.. 
I have little experience in Java but I have no experience in Android development. The research so far has given me nothing on how to go about this. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would much appreciate it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 would be [mounting the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421826/whats-android-file-system). Since Android is Linux based, there's a huge array of filesystems available, and individual vendors may or may not decide to write their own filesystems, just for the fun of it. On Windows, your options include [ext2fsd or ext2read](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/does-a-ext4-reader-for-windows-exist), among other possibilities.

Once you've got the filesystem mounted, then you get to deal with the per-application data storage. I'd wager a fair amount of applications use [SQLite3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), because it is an amazing tool. But you'll have to figure out, for each type of data you want to read, where it is stored and in what format. (The standard `file(1)` tool on Linux systems can come in handy, it knows heuristics that are surprisingly good at showing what type of file you might be dealing with.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the .apk of an application, a tool such as [**dex2jar**](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/), used in combinaison with something like [**jd-gui**](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), can get you the JAVA source-code of the application *(which can help, if not obfuscated)*.

After that, an .apk is basically a zip-file -- which means opening it with an unzip-ing application will allow you to get the images and resources it uses.

Then, databases used by Android applications tend to be SQLite, on which you can do SQL queries, using an SQLite client.