# Android file system

Tags: android, linux

I have an Android emulator running, and am trying to figure out the file system. It doesn't seem to be 100% standard Linux layout.

Anyway, when opening a DDMS file browser, I get 3 folders at the "root": `data`, `mnt` and `system`. When running `ls /` from a shell, I get a much longer and different list. What is going on here?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421826/whats-android-file-system

Answer (score 0):

Android has the 100% linux file system.The adb tool shows the correct file structure, its the DDMS(ADT in particular) which is not showing all the directories due to some reasons(probably security reasons).

Comment: there is no `/lib`, `/bin`, `/var` or `/usr`, to name a few differences. So this is not 100% linux