# Reading specific String from text file using non-activity Java Class

Tags: java, android

I have a text file and it has -

```
packagename:com.hello
```

I have non-activity Java Class which has to read this text file fetch this com.hello and output it in the form of Log or Toast Message. I am doing Programming in Android in Eclipse. I have 2 questions..

1) Where do I need to place this text file I mean the location of it so that my JAva Class can read it.

2) Since my JAva Class is non-activity class, openFileInput is not working since it needs context and I have no way of getting context.

```
FileInputStream in = openFileInput("filename.txt");
```

Is there any way of doing it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is your problm solvd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Where do I need to place this text file I mean the location of it so that my JAva Class can read it.

Anywhere you want, just tell your app the correct path to the file.

> 2) Since my JAva Class is non-activity class, openFileInput is not working since it needs context and I have no way of getting context.

**Just read the file in Java!!!**

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/your/file.txt"));
```

NOTES:

- you must throw or catch a `FileNotFoundException`
- remember closing the stream when finished!!

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and I am giving it as FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(" /home/Myself/git/github/HelloApp/filename.txt")); 
It is giving filenotfoundexception

Comment: Then I need to put my text file in assets folder but getAssets() wont work for non-activity when I use   AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

Comment: absolutely **not**, don't care you have an Activity or not, `getAssets()` is simply a shortcut, but [**Android FileSystem**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421826/what-is-androids-file-system) remains the same... But if you don't want to use straight, then get the asset statically from an Activity class, something like `UtilityActivity.getAsset(fileName);`

Comment: Ok so I adb push my text file to '/data/local/' and then from Java Class, I use this  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(" /data/local/filename.txt"));
This should work ?

Answer (score 1):

1)You can place it anywhere inside your package ; just ensure you provide the correct path.
 2)Refer this : [How can I read a text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and I am placing my file in /home/Myself/git/github/HelloApp/filename.txt and I am getting FileNotFoundException... HelloApp is my app name