# Impact of writing to multiple opened files

Tags: java, android, file-io, filesystems, bufferedoutputstream

I am trying to optimize the logging system of an Android application which causes some unwanted latency. There are multiple files opened which log different parts and should be kept separate.

I am not very familiar with low-level filesystem design and even less with current flash and/or SSD memory used in mobile phones (opposed to traditional HDD). I assume that memory is organized in disk blocks (512B or 4096B more recently) and some form of continuous, linked or indexed allocations is used. 
I am using `BufferedOutputStream`s with buffer size of 256B, but this values is chosen at random ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream) provides a good answer for buffer size).

**Writing in append mode to multiple opened files creates additional overhead that can significantly decrease performance (from allocation strategy for ex.)? Is it influenced greatly by the buffered output buffer size (this particular case of multiple files)?**

I am using Android which tends to have a variety of [FS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421826/what-is-androids-file-system)s and makes it hard to understand how each influences the append to multiple opened files. Probably the I/O functions of Java or any other are very similar.

My search for this particular issue turned empty or maybe I need some domain specific terms in my search that I am not familiar with.

Comment: 256 bytes for a buffer? You want to have it slow?

Comment: How many open files?

Comment: @greenapps Not more than 20, but all of them are closed at once. Concurrently writing would be done in like 5-6 files, while the rest are hanging around opened.